# Как настроить на первом жестком диске Linux на втором Windows

Tags: linux, windows, grub, dual-boot

Возникла необходимость, чтобы на одном компьютере были доступны две операционные системы: Linux и Windows. Я хочу, чтобы обе системы располагались на двух разных физических дисках, т.е. вариант с разбивкой одного жесткого диска на разделы меня не устраивает.

Главное что интересует, это как подключить два диска, чтобы загружался загрузчик Grub, и был выбор операционной системы, аналогично, как это бывает при разбивке на разделы.

У кого есть подобный опыт настройки или какие-либо мысли на этот счёт, очень жду от вас комментариев.

Comment: Ну собственно после установки linux - grub ищет все поддерживаемые ОС на всех винтах и добавляет их в список. Или ты уже так пробовал и оно не поехало?

Comment: *аналогично, как это бывает при разбивке на разделы* — это абсолютно идентичные и ничем не отличимые друг от друга ситуации.

Comment: вот же http://igorka.com.ua/2009-08-02/grub-zagruzka-windows-so-vtorogo-zhestkogo-diska/

Comment: @don Rumata Спасибо за ответ. Нет, я пока не пробовал, я хочу разобраться в вопросе, прежде чем купить второй SSD.

Comment: @alexander barakin Ясно, спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: @coder675 супер

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Настоятельно рекомендую первой ОС поставить виндовоз, т.к. в процессе своей установки данная ОС сносит начисто всё, что не понимает. Поэтому, сделайте так:

1. Установите виндовоз на любой из дисков.
2. Проверьте, что загрузка идёт нормально
3. Вставьте установочный носитель линуха и начните установку
4. Когда установщик прелдожит Вам конфигурацию, скажите, что Вы сами желаете распределить дисковое пространство и укажите свободный диск для установки линуха
5. Когда установщик будет настраивать загрузчик ОС, он спросит, следует ли включать виндовоз в список загрузки Подтвердите это.

Всё !

Comment: спасибо за совет, но советую внимательно прочитать мой вопрос, мне нужно установить две системы Linux и Windows на двух отдельных жестких дисках, и чтобы в процессе загрузки был выбор ОС используя загрузчик GRUB. Т.е. без разницы какую ОС ставить первой, т.к. используется 2 отдельных физических диска, один Primary, второй в Slave в биосе.
 В комментариях см.выше мне уже дали исчерпывающий ответ по этой теме, необходимо прописать конфиг GRUB в LINUX и диск с Linux переключить в биосе на Primary, чтобы загрузка начиналась с него.

Comment: **советую внимательно прочитать мой вопрос, мне нужно установить две системы Linux и Windows на двух отдельных жестких дисках, и чтобы в процессе загрузки был выбор ОС используя загрузчик GRUB** 

Именно такая система у меня стоит дома. Первый диск с люнихом - для работы, второй диск, с виндой - для игры в "Цивилизацию". Первый диск - сигэйт, второй - вестерн диджитал.  И ёмкость у них разная... После включения компа появляется меню grub и я выбираю, что загружать.

Comment: **без разницы какую ОС ставить первой** - ещё раз повторяю - Вы ошибаетесь. Более того, эта скотина, которая винда, в последнее время стала даже после автоматического обновления портить порядок загрузки. Приходится каждый раз восстанавливать вручную.

Comment: Можете, разумеется. мне не верить, но я такую конфигурацию (с двумя HD) использую уже лет 15 и переустанавливал таким образом много разных версий и винды и люниха.  Ещё один практический совет...  В винде нет (во всяком случае - ещё совсем недавно не было) понятия о UTF времени. В часах BIOS (которые с батарейкой) винда хранит ЛОКАЛЬНОЕ время. А люних - UTF (по умолчанию). Из-за этого возникают конфликты при последовательной перезагрузке.  Плюс к этому, в винде обновления по часовым поясам и летнему времени всегда выходят с большой задержкой.

Comment: ладно, буду пробовать. Но если пройти по ссылке http://igorka.com.ua/2009-08-02/grub-zagruzka-windows-so-vtorogo-zhestkogo-diska/, пишут что можно конфиг Grub вручную править, поэтому не понял, зачем соблюдать очередность, может врут ))

Comment: **пишут что можно конфиг Grub вручную править, поэтому не понял, зачем соблюдать очередность** - конечно - можно! Но зачем ?! Если всё это можно сделать на полном автомате ? Если будете править в ручную, не забудьте потом выполнить команду *update-grub* с правами рута.

Comment: **но сейчас у нас есть возможность загрузить только Ubuntu (GRUB пока ничего не знает о втором диске с Windows).** - именно поэтому я Вам и советую поступить в точности наоборот: сначала установить винду (котороя хоть как, ничего не знает про Убунту), а потом - на другой диск - Убунту. И инсталлятор убуны автоматически обнаружит винду (он Вам об этом скажет) и автоматически включит её в меню grub. РУКАМИ ничего править не придётся!